# find if ArrayList contains atleat one different string

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `Arraylist` of Strings that may or may not contain duplicates,

`list = ["car", "car", "car"]` OR  `list = ["car", "car", "bike", "car"]`

I want to know something like below,

```
if(list contains All same strings)
 same = true
else if(list contains atleast one different element)
 same = false
```

Please help me out in writing above condition.

Comment: I like both answers, from Naman & Sprinter. But not sure which one to use. I use java 1.8 environment. Which one of these 2 answers is more efficient??

Comment: I think you should go with @sprinter 's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Put all values in a `Set` and check if size is 1 or more.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("car", "car", "bike", "car");
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);
boolean same;

if (unique.size() > 1) {
    same = false;
} else {
    same = true;
}
System.out.println(same); // prints false
System.out.println(list); // prints [car, car, bike, car]
```

Comment: But it will remove the duplicate elements.

Comment: i added the comment based on the comment -  "Put all values in a Set and check if size is 1 or more." . You edited it later. Now its fine.:)

Comment: @Rehman, Sorry, what did I edit? Can you post my previous comment. And check out the updated code with output.

Comment: @Rehman If you could give me reason behind **down voting my answer** then that would be great. I will keep that in my mind.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Missed one line. Voted up

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Java 8 then this is very simple:

```
same = list.stream().distinct().count() > 1
```

If you are not familiar with streams, you can interpret this statement as: create a stream of the items in the list, filter out any duplicates and then count the number of unique items left in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

containsAll() can check the list for whether all passed parameter is present or not. It accepts Collection type parameter as argument so make one more list pass only one parameter in that list and pass this as parameter to containsAll(). Following is dummy workable code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Car");
    list.add("Car");
    list.add("Car");

    List<String> paramlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    paramlist.add("Car");
    boolean same = false;
    if(list.containsAll(paramlist)){
        same = true;
    }
    else{
        same = false;
    }

}
```